# The PYTHONPATH environment variable does not populate sys.path

Tags: python, pythonpath

In:  WINDOWS PowerShell, Python 3.10.7
I added environment variables

```
PS C:\Users\luoyf\Desktop> $env:PYTHONPATH
PS C:\Users\luoyf\Desktop> $env:PYTHONPATH="D:\Workspace"
PS C:\Users\luoyf\Desktop> $env:PYTHONPATH
D:\Workspace
PS C:\Users\luoyf\Desktop> python
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os; os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
'D:\\Workspace'
>>> import sys; sys.path
['C:\\tool\\python-3.10.7\\python310.zip', 'C:\\tool\\python-3.10.7', 'C:\\tool\\python-3.10.7\\lib\\site-packages']
>>>
```

Why is there no 'D:Workspace' in the sys.path environment variable, obviously PYTHONPATH exists.

Comment: Just tried this and it works absolutely fine for me (Python 3.9.2, Windows 10; also Python 3.10.7, exactly the same build you have).

Comment: How did you install Python? A customized `site.py` could do this. So could a `sitecustomize.py`, f/e. And if this were someone using a UNIXy shell, I'd be asking them to look for shell functions or aliases wrapping their Python interpreter.

Comment: Anyhow -- we really need instructions we could follow to make this happen on any machine other than yours for this question to be answerable.

Comment: @AKX I reinstalled the python, then the problem has been solved, thank you

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I download the 'Windows embeddable package (64-bit)' and unzip it, and then download the get-pip.py to get the pip. Now i has reinstall the python, then the problem has been solved, thank you